# open() "/path/to/include" failed (13: Permission denied) for nginx include

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am getting a really odd issue and I am not sure what is causing it. I am trying to setup a test VPS (using Digital Ocean and CentOS 7.6), to test some Ansible scripts I have.

The script generates this config file:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    set $socket /var/run/php-fpm/deploy.sock;
    server_name servername.com;

    root /home/deploy/project/current/public/;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/servername.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/servername.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dhparams.pem;

    #charset koi8-r;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/project.access.log  main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project.error.log;

    include /srv/server-config/nginx/includes.d/maintenance.inc;
    include /srv/server-config/nginx/includes.d/silverstripe-4.inc;
}
```

The include `include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;` loads without issue (as far as I can tell), but the include `include /srv/server-config/nginx/includes.d/maintenance.inc;` fails with the error: `open() "/path/to/include" failed (13: Permission denied)`.

I have double and tripple checked the permissions and the directories in the path all appear to be `drwxr-xr-x` and the files are both `-rw-r--r--`.

If I comment out the line `include /srv/server-config/nginx/includes.d/maintenance.inc;` then the next line throws the same error.

I am running the same config/setup on a handfull of live VPS' (older versions of CentOS7) and don't get this error. Has something updated in the latest CentOS that might cause this (maybe nginx can't include files outside of /etc/)? If not, does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Any help with this appreciated, as I am banging my head on the keyboard trying to work this out :-/.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after restarting my machine, and I finally found out that it was caused by `SElinux` being enabled.

To disable `SElinux` temporarily:

```
setenforce 0
```